# HTMLPurifier allow centered text

Tags: htmlpurifier

I am needing the code that will allow my users to input centered text and not have htmlpurifier strip it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grabbing half the answer from your(?) [HTML Purifier thread](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,5659):

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'text-align');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

That's the first step. If you want to disallow anything but `center` as in that thread, you would change the CSS `AttrDef` for `text-align`:

```
$css = $purifier->getCSSDefinition();
$css->info['text-align'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Enum(array('center'));

// should allow text-align:center but not text-align:right or the likes:
$purifier->purify(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration of HTML Purifier will not strip centered text.

Comment: Unless they've centered it with the `<center>` tag, one assumes.

Comment: Nah, we convert that into CSS styling.

Comment: Ah. Clever. I like HTML Purifier more and more the more I learn about it.